# How to AspNetCore Versioning With 3 digits (1.0.0) instead of two (1.0)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have developed an api that use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` and it will be consumed by a flutter mobile app. The mobile app developers are asking me if the api versioning can be with 3 digits instead of two. Example: `1.0.0` instead of `1.0`

**Can anyone know how to achive this?**

Comment: and how it will be useful for them ?

Comment: they just said that it would be better for flutter with no additional arguments. I said I look if its possible.

Comment: as far as I know it is not supported. you can check this [link](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-api-versioning/) if you something is helpful